# Should I install 64-bit Ubuntu onto my 32-bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, hardware, windows-vista, system-requirements

I own a Toshiba Laptop with the following details:

- AMD Turion X2 64 Mobile Technology TL-60 2.00 GHz Processor
- 3 GB of RAM
- 32-bit Windows Vista

Does this machine meet the requirements to run 64-bit Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - as statet on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Turion#Turion_64_X2) and the [AMD Website](http://products.amd.com/en-gb/NotebookCPUDetail.aspx?id=6) it is indeed an 64bit processor and capable of running 64bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Your PC could run a 64bit version of Ubuntu however for your system I'd personally stick with the 32bit version... It'll run quicker.

Comment: Can you found your claim on proofs?

Comment: You can see right here than his CPU is 64bit compatible...
(http://products.amd.com/pages/notebookcpudetail.aspx?id=6&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: I think @the_Seppi was talking about the second part of your claim (that 32-bit will run faster).

Comment: 64bit Operating Systems require more resources (mainly RAM) He could run a 64bit OS but he'd likely have better performance running a 32bit version. I have tried Ubuntu 15.04 and with nothing installed it will idle around 1.5GB RAM usage... that would be half his RAM used up on the OS alone...

Comment: In almost all cases code compiled to 64 bit will run faster than code compiled to 32 bit.  There are only some situations where it won't, such as when severely low on RAM, and 1.5GB almost certainly does not constitute such a situation.  You may also be exaggerating the additional RAM usage of a 64 bit application - only code, not data, will have the larger pointers and so on, and this is only a fraction of RAM used by a process.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that Ubuntu takes up less resources that what Windows does, so I would say give it a go. If it does not work out the worst that will happen is that you will have to clean it all down and start again. From the sound of the previous posts though, it sounds like you will be OK.

Most of my posts these days seem to have the letters (vm) in them, but I feel this could be a good option for you here. Download both iso's and then run them in a vm. This way you might be able to get a feel of it, before jumping all the way in with a 64 bit os.